# Why is Object.Equals(new Object(), new Object()) false?

Tags: c#, boolean, reference-type

Why is the following piece of code `false`?

```
Object.Equals(new Object(), new Object())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)

> The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for
>   reference types, and bitwise equality for value types. Reference
>   equality means the object references that are compared refer to the
>   same object. Bitwise equality means the objects that are compared have
>   the same binary representation.

In other words, you are creating two different objects of the same type and seeing if they are the exact same object, which they are not.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx):

> The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for reference types, and bitwise equality for value types. **Reference equality means the object references that are compared refer to the same object**. Bitwise equality means the objects that are compared have the same binary representation.

Note that a derived type might override the Equals method to implement value equality. Value equality means the compared objects have the same value but different binary representations.

You are creating two different Objects.